# How do I configure my browsers not to save passwords for specific websites?

Tags: safari, google-chrome, password, firefox

There are certain web sites whose passwords I don't want saved, for security reasons. I want to type them in manually whenever needed.

How do I configure Safari, Chrome and Firefox on Mavericks to not save passwords for these web sites, and not to ask me?

I don't want my browsers to ask me whether to remember the password for these web sites, because I can (and have) selected Yes without thinking, say when I'm in a hurry.

Comment: This is like 5 questions in one!

Comment: Nope, just one question, regarding three browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple questions here, I would attempt to answer one of them:

In case of Firefox:

Open the permissions manager

in the address bar type following `about:permissions` and hit enter

In the new window select the web site to work on and choose the settings.

[image: permissions]

To further customize a specific web site (fine tune) click on the small Icon in front of that website address. In the new pop up window you can highly customize what that web site can and can not do.

Comment: What about Chrome and Safari?

Comment: Please ask those as separate questions. As pointed out in my comment, you are asking multiple questions and that is not how this site works. The procedure for each browser would be different.

Answer (score 0):

On your iOS an Android devices you can use an app that will manage the passwords and log in for you. These apps clear up the cache and store the passwords in a secure manager. You can lock them with a password as well.
I'm using LoginBox, which I found to be the best solution around.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, John, but the question was not about mobile devices, and not about password managers, either.